# What exactly Resource manager do?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Can anybody explain me what exactly Resource manager do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you can use this for creating internationalized applications.
It is a single point of access that allows you to retrieve internationalized data from your resource bundles.

Here are some useful official links on the matter:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/resources/ResourceManager.html
- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_6.html

And some unofficial:

- http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2008/01/22/localizing-flex-applications
- http://www.visible-form.com/blog/flex-localization-with-resource-bundles/

Cheers